# Configuring Heartbeat to run shell script

Tags: linux, shell, cluster

I set up a high availability system with [Heartbeat](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat), I wish that when there was a drop in the main cluster and the secondary cluster was activated, Heartbeat start in it and execute a shell script.

- Contents of `/etc/ha.d/haresources`

  ```
  master IPaddr::10.0.0.1/24 test.sh
  ```
- Contents of `/etc/ha.d/ha.cf`

  ```
  autojoin none
  debugfile /var/log/ha-debug
  logfile /var/log/ha-log
  logfacility local0
  ucast ens32 10.0.0.3 
  ucast ens32 10.0.0.2
  udpport 694 
  use_logd yes
  keepalive 1
  deadtime 10
  warntime 5
  initdead 20
  node master
  node slave
  auto_failback on
  ```

I gave execute permission to the script and put it in the path `/etc/init.d/`, but I still could not get it executed through Heartbeat, is this type of procedure possible?

Comment: Could you add your `/etc/ha.d/ha.cnf` ?

Comment: This sounds more like a job for *cluster resource manager* instead of Heartbeat. And indeed I was able to find this article describing a solution: [Pacemaker - Execute script on failover](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Corosync_Pacemaker_-_Execute_a_script_on_failover.html). If it solves your problem you could later answer your own question with details on how you did it.

Comment: If you would execute `hostname` command, does it returns "master"?

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík i will check this option, thanks

Comment: @Alex yes, I configured the clusters this way because I'm configuring in test environment.